# CSS only menu expanding on display of child elements

Tags: css

I have this simple responsive CSS-only menu. It had a single break point of 760px, now I have a small difficulty. The difficulty is when the menu is above 760px (please expand the Fiddle result to see) .

Here's the fiddle : [Fiddle menu](http://jsfiddle.net/tpcjd8La/1/)

Now see when you hover over the first a (say you hover over home), you'll notice that the li or a expands, and I don't know why. I have gone through a lot of code online and I don't see why, that expansion is triggered on hover.

Actually the menu code is partially [copied from this tutorial](http://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/), and in the above example the menu works fine, but not in mine (unfortunately there's no place you can download the source for the tutorial).

So, why is the menu expanding ?

Below is the HTML code for my menu :

```
<label for="showmenu">Show Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="showmenu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Banner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Banner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

One hack though, as I have found out is adding `position:absolute` to the parent `ul`. But I'd still like somebody to explain, why is the menu expanding?

### Note

Please make sure you expand the fiddle results view and once you see the li's floated left, then only hover over any given dropdown li .

Comment: Hey Alex, Are you talking that the "HOME" button expand a little bit wider than it's original size?

Comment: @pSyToR Yup :D thats wht i'am talking about

Comment: Look my answer below, it's a "double" application of the same CSS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shyam Babu Kushwaha was saying the code he mentionned is actually working properly if you add it to you CSS.

```
ul li a + ul li {
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

For your question, *But i'd still like somebody to come along and explain , why is the menu expanding ?*

Basically what's happening (even though we don't see it inside Firebug - *HTML / CSS debug from Firefox*) it's the following code that is applying a second time (which is why it expand for 1px)...

```
ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

The above code from: Shyam Babu Kushwaha will correct your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please update below css declaration:

```
ul li a + ul li {
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: ! i want to know WHY my code does't work , not , HOW to make it work . Thanks though .

Comment: You can found it from my answer. You declared 1px right margin in li, so it was also affecting li inside submenu and was increasing parent width 1px. This is the reason.

Comment: The 1px is quite important Alexander do not remove it that's what make the 1px line between each menu but it will "reapply" when you hover over the "MENU"

Comment: I am only removing this in li's within submenu ul.